# problem implementing decorator in permission guard

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm new with Nestjs .

and I am implementing `Authorization` using `Casl`.

for that I've made a `decorator` like this

```js
import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';

export const Permission = (action:string,subject: string) => SetMetadata(action, subject);
```

and also I have made `Permission guard`

```js
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CaslAbilityFactory } from './ability.factory';
import { Action } from './action.enum';
import { User } from 'src/persistent/entity/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class PermissionGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private reflector: Reflector,
    private caslAbilityFactory: CaslAbilityFactory
  ) { }
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const action = this.reflector.get<Action>('action', context.getHandler());
    const subject = this.reflector.get<string>('subject', context.getHandler());

    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.user
    console.log('**',action,subject) // undefined undefined

    return this.matchPermission(user, action, subject)
  }

}
```

and I'm using them like this in `user controller`

```js
@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
  constructor( private readonly userUsecase: UserUsecase) { }
  
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard,PermissionGuard)
  @Permission(Action.Create,'User')
  @Post()
  create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto,@Request() req) {
    return this.userUsecase.create(createUserDto,req.user)
  }
}
```

as you see in the permission guard I cant get decorator value .

and it prints **undefined**

what's the problem and How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that

I am trying to retrieve the metadata set by the `@Permission` decorator using the wrong `key` in the `PermissionGuard`

to solve that

I modified decorator like this

```js
import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';

export const Permission = (action:string,subject: string) => SetMetadata('permission', {subject,action});
```

and also modified guard

```js
    const permission:any = this.reflector.get<Action>('permission', context.getHandler());
    const {subject,action} = permission
```

and now it works correctly